# Sort Table values Ascending & Decending with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have the following table which am trying to sort to Ascending & Descending order `onclick` with the following JavaScript Code:

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Date <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Views <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Clicks <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(3)">CTR <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Earned <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(5)">eCPM <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-30</td>
      <td>4133</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0.07%</td>
      <td>$0.03</td>
      <td>$0.0073</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-29</td>
      <td>8340</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0.06%</td>
      <td>$0.05</td>
      <td>$0.006</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-28</td>
      <td>7410</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0.07%</td>
      <td>$0.025</td>
      <td>$0.0034</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-27</td>
      <td>3796</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0.05%</td>
      <td>$0.01</td>
      <td>$0.0026</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-26</td>
      <td>4005</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0.05%</td>
      <td>$0.01</td>
      <td>$0.0025</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-25</td>
      <td>2070</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0.1%</td>
      <td>$0.01</td>
      <td>$0.0048</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-24</td>
      <td>1016</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>0.59%</td>
      <td>$0.03</td>
      <td>$0.0295</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-23</td>
      <td>1503</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0.27%</td>
      <td>$0.02</td>
      <td>$0.0133</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-22</td>
      <td>1665</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>0.66%</td>
      <td>$0.055</td>
      <td>$0.033</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-21</td>
      <td>1340</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>0.75%</td>
      <td>$0.05</td>
      <td>$0.0373</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-20</td>
      <td>1489</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>0.87%</td>
      <td>$0.065</td>
      <td>$0.0437</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-19</td>
      <td>1745</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0.29%</td>
      <td>$0.025</td>
      <td>$0.0143</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-18</td>
      <td>962</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0.52%</td>
      <td>$0.025</td>
      <td>$0.026</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-17</td>
      <td>779</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>1.03%</td>
      <td>$0.04</td>
      <td>$0.0513</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem here is it's working properly with the same number of digits but not with different numbers of digits.
For example if a column contains: `1, 5, 3`

It gets sorted as expected. `1, 3, 5` & `5, 3, 1`

But if the column contains: `5, 3, 11`

It gets sorted as: `11, 3, 5` & `5, 3, 11`

How do I get them sorted correctly?

Comment: Try using parseInt(); Like parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase());

Comment: You are comparing strings `'1', '11','2' etc..` not numbers `1,2,11,etc...`

Comment: You can't compare `innerHTML` values reliably numerically as your columns are text including formatting such as `%` and `$`. You have to store each raw value i.e: `0.03` separately, i.e: a `data-value` attribute and then sort against that value. You most likely need different ways to compare depending if it is a full number only or possibly decimals, float, etc..You might need to add a `data-type` attribute to add a `switch` over to ensure you use the correct way to compare the values. Look into comparing decimals, numbers, etc.. and re-post the code when done if you still got issues then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a number of different formats, what you'll probably want to do is attempt to extract out the numerical portion of the number.

You can attempt to do this with RegExp, checking for common numerical patterns and then parsing to a simple number. If I was architecting this, I'd probably have an array of different matching and converting functions for each supported format.

Something like this:

```js
const patterns = [
      { test: /\$[0-9\.,]+/, transform: str => parseFloat(str.replace(/[$,]/g, '')) },
      { test: /[0-9\.,]+%/, transform: str => parseFloat(str.replace(/[%,]/g, '')) }
    ];
    
const convert = str => {
  const pattern = patterns.find(({ test }) => test.test(str));
  
  return pattern && pattern.transform(str) || str;
};

const converted = ['$1,234.56', '1,234.56%', 'not a num'].map(str => convert(str));
console.log(converted);
```

Then, for each field, run it through all the patterns until you find a match, convert them, then do a numeric sort. You can also leave the ones that don't get converted as strings and let it just do a string-like sort for those.

In your code, if you used something like I had, you'd just change your comparison lines to something like this:

```
if (convert(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > convert(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()))
```

Also, a tip for dates: I would recommend converting dates into either timestamps or a common format (such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, which is biggest to smallest), which will then allow you to properly compare and sort multiple date formats in a single column.

---

Below was original answer, which didn't account for symbols with the numbers.

Your problem is you are doing a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison.

A string comparison will sort string numbers just like it does alphabets. For example, anything that starts with a 1 will always come before anything that starts with a 2, even if it's "1365872685623876723" against "2".

Instead, change these lines:

```
x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()
```

To parse them to numbers with `parseInt()` first:

```
parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > parseInt(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())
```

That'll make it do a numerical sort.

Comment: This is only going to work if the values to be sorted are full numbers. Sorting the columns with `%` and `$` values won'r sort as `parseInt()` doesn't fix the issue. The required solution will have to be more elaborate where OP most likely has to store the actual raw numerical inside a data attribute or similar and sort by it instead. Though the decimal values could potentially call for a different solution, other than `parseInt`

Comment: Hmm, good catch. I didn't see any info about that in the text, but a closer look at the sample data does have those. Fun. =p

Comment: @Fran I updated my answer with hopefully a more relevant solution.

Comment: @samanime  It's working for numbers & percentages like 90838 & 0.08% but not for dates & currencies like 2017-11-30 & $1.42 respectively.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't give patterns for every possible entry. If you just add more values to the `patterns` array to convert each other value, you can add conversions for everything you may need.